# Can we assign less array contents at array inline declaration?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, language-lawyer

I got an array `A` which encapsulates `M` arrays of type `B`. Each such `B` array has `3-components`. 
However, i need my entries to be padded to `4 components`. One way to do this, is to modify my values to have a 4-th zero component as:

```
uint16_t A[M][4] = {{a0,a1,a2,0}, {a3,a4,a5,0}, ... , {aM-1,aM,aM+1,0}};
```

However, i realize i can declare A as follows and clang is not complaining:

```
uint16_t A[M][4] = {{a0,a1,a2}, {a3,a4,a5}, ... , {aM-1,aM,aM+1}};
```

Is this legal? would A's entries be expanded by the compiler to include a 4-th component? Can you please point in the C-standard (PEP) where can i see this behavior explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be valid.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, *Initialization*

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no
>   designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according
>   to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, [...]

and then, (*emphasis mine*)

> The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a
>   particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject;<sup>151)</sup>
>   **all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as
>   objects that have static storage duration.**

Comment: Thanks, the combination of the brace-enclosed description and the following statement explains that to me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 19 The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each
>   initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any
>   previously listed initializer for the same subobject;151) **all
>   subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized
>   implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

and

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
>   unsigned) **zero**;

And from the C++ Standard (8.5.1 Aggregates)

> 7 If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are
>   members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized
>   shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there
>   is no brace-or-equalinitializer, **from an empty initializer list**
>   (8.5.4)

And (8.5 Initializers)

> 3 List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined
>   as follows:
>
> — Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is
>   **value-initialized**.

and further

> 8 To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — otherwise, the object is **zero-initialized**.